# Excel VBA Opening Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I used to call an application from VBA/Excel. This was done via Internet Explorer and without human intervention.

This week, Windows 11 was installed. Now MS Edge opens automatically and invariably asks if the application should be opened.

Is there any way that I can skip this question? The application is working perfectly, but I just want to automatically open the application.

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = False
    .navigate "https://robostorage.blob.core.windows.net/clickonce/PbnPlayer/RoboBridge.PbnPlayer.application?pbnFileName=" & oefRobInp
End With
```

Comment: Is there anybody who can help?

Comment: Disappointing ...